# In osm2pgsql flex output, many road types I retrieve are highway: construction? How do I find what road type they are?

Tags: openstreetmap, road, osm2pgsql, flex

I am using pgosm-flex to load in the OpenStreetMap OSM files for many files.  I then passed in many (latitude,longitude) points to get the nearest road type to those points.  The query works, but the problem is, sometimes the road type (highway tag) is construction.

According to OpenStreetMap guidelines, when construction is going on in a road, the road type is updated to highway: construction.  Then, another tag should be added that says (e.g. construction: trunk_link).  Not all of the roads that have highway:construction seem to have the construction tag as well.

How can I get what type of road a road tagged as construction is?

Are there other columns I can use?

Comment: If the construction tag is missing then it is missing. If you know the area you can use an OSM editor like JOSM or iD and add new tags  based on your own knowledge.